# Using partially redundant phrases such as "blatantly obvious" in a sentence for emphasis

Tags: grammaticality

Would it be grammatically correct to use phrases like blatantly obvious or hugely massive in a sentence? The words themselves have different enough meanings that I would think it is okay.

Comment: "Blatantly obvious", though redundant, is idiomatic.  Hugely massive is not idiomatic and might come across as hyperbole, IMO.

Comment: And one should never use excessive hyperbole.

Comment: It might be grammatically correct, but stylistically it is a bit unkosher.

Comment: Yes, let's avoid being egregiously mistaken. But let's do keep the astoundingly variegated forms of English as they are.

Comment: 'Colorless green ideas sleep absolutely furiously' is perfectly grammatical. But hasn't got much else going for it.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - I wonder where you can get your hands on some of those ideas?  I wouldn't mind sleeping furiously for once.

Comment: @Hot Licks Possibly people who are fast asleep are furiously bed-ridden.

Answer (score 1):

Without doubt, the construction of an adverb followed by an adjective that it modifies is grammatically correct.

The examples provided are not grammatically wrong, although as commenters have noted they are stylistically and perhaps logically flawed.

"*Blatantly obvious*" is at best a well worn cliche.  Strictly speaking it is not redundant, because *blatant* indicates an annoyingly assertive sound.

(*The word originated in 1596, when Edmund Spenser coined it to describe a many-tongued "Blatant Beast"; according to the OED the word survived through the late 19th C in the sense of "noisily annoying."  More recent usage has backformed the cliche into a dubious synonym for "obvious."  At least one can make the case that it's not redundant in this instance, even though as the commenters say, it's probably not the best writing choice.*)

"Hugely massive" seems redundant to me, but I'll not cast the initially first petrified rock at it.

To answer precisely, the expressions are grammatically right.

Comment: Strictly speaking, the original sense of 'blatant' you mention is now a secondary meaning according to say AHDEL, ODO, Macmillan and Collins, and you are falling foul of the etymological fallacy.

Answer (score 0):

I've always been taught to avoid using words like *obvious* or *palpable* in academic writing.  It should be up to the reader to determine what is and what isn't obvious. So, in academic writing, I would advise that you definitely avoid using *blatantly obvious*.

Comment: Who says this is academic writing? That is not patently obvious.

Comment: @Lambie I can't comment yet...